# Dual boot with Windows 7 stopped working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS a few days ago on a brand new SSD, which was empty (sda), and kept the Windows 7 install which is on a separate SSD (sdb). Grub was installed properly (I guess on sda?) and after installing Ubuntu, I could select what system to start, from the grub menu. I tried that right after installation, and it did work fine.

But this morning, when I tried to restart Windows from the grub menu, I got the following error message:

```
error: no such device: 2844473F44470F4E.
Setting partition type to 0x7

Press any key to continue...
```

Now I cannot start my Windows system anymore. Any idea what has gone wrong, and how I could fix that?

Additional info that may help:

The initial fstab after Ubuntu install was:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=27e8f423-5046-4bf4-8bf6-3ca19a440e9c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a123385a-2e28-45da-a699-574f26e43b54 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

which I changed (to add a network drive) into:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=27e8f423-5046-4bf4-8bf6-3ca19a440e9c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a123385a-2e28-45da-a699-574f26e43b54 none            swap    sw              0       0
# added on october 25, 2016, following instructions @ http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/map-network-drive-onto-ubuntu-14-04/
//192.168.0.1/data                         /media/z        cifs    credentials=/home/jfs/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777   0       0
```

After trying boot-repair (see comments, it did not help so far), the report can be found at:
http://paste2.org/AVeadskx

Comment: boot into ubuntu and run from terminal `sudo update-grub`. Let us know, if that helped

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just tried, unfortunately, it didn't do much, I still get the same error...

Comment: OK, another possibility is to use boot-repair. Visit this page and install boot-repair in ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . The launch it a do Recommended repair

Comment: I tried Boot-Repair, it ran ok. After restarting I have some grub entries which have disappeared (memory test, etc.), I can still boot linux, but I still get the same error when trying to boot windows...

Comment: Very strange. Have you done any changes to fstab, or renamed your partitions via Disks or gparted?

Comment: I added the following line to /etc/fstab, to add a network drive: `//192.168.0.1/data                         /media/z        cifs    credentials=/home/jfs/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777   0       0` Is that bad?

Comment: Please, post whole /etc/fstab to your question. I believe the problem would lie here

Comment: It's missing the Windos parition. This is little bit blind call, so please, make a backup of /etc/fstab somewhere. I am posting it as a answer

Comment: Windows is installed on a separate hard drive, so is it really supposed to show up in this fstab?

Comment: I am unsure, thats why I called it blind shot. If this edit would be incorrect, you can skip mounting it anytime during the boottime.

Comment: Better to post link to entire Summary Report from Boot-Repair. But Windows if originally on sda, may be confused on which drive it now is. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Thanks, I just added the link at the end of the question. Hope this can help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, I fixed my problem by fixing the boot sector of the drive on which Windows was installed (sdb). For that I used a "Windows repair disk".

I guess that the issue came from Grub having changed something on my Windows drive (maybe during grub update) but not sure...

Step by step instructions:

1. I got a repair disk for my version of Windows (in my case 7, 64 bits). If you have one, use it. If you don't, you can use any Windows 7 computer to burn one (see e.g. https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-create-a-windows-7-system-repair-disc-2626301)
2. I disconnected my Linux drive (sda), to prevent any writing on it during the process.
3. I configured the BIOS to start on the CD drive.
4. I booted on the repair disk, and chose the option to start a "dos" command prompt.
5. I ran the two commands:

   ```
   bootrec /fixmbr
   bootrec /fixboot
   ```
6. I checked the BIOS to make sure that the computer would boot on sda first (linux drive with Grub), and sdb with lower priority (windows).

After that, I reconnected the Linux drive. Now I can use Grub to boot on the two systems. I also configured Linux to mount `/dev/sdb` read only to prevent Linux from writing the windows drive in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the '//192.168.0.1/data /media/z cifs credentials=/home/jfs/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=100‌​0,uid=1000,file_mode‌​=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0' line and restart.

Comment: Hi, I already tried that, and it did not fix the issue